# cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(..) returns cudaErrorUnknown; what are possible error sources?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpu

I am using the CUDA runtime API. In my kernel file's host code I do the following:

```
unsigned char* pData = new unsigned char[2*256*256*256]();

glTexImage3D(
  nTextureID, // created before (glBindTexture etc.)
  0, 
  nInternalFormat, // GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA
  256, 
  256, 
  256, 
  0, 
  nDataFormat, // GL_LUMINANCE8_ALPHA8
  nDataType, // GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE
  pData);

/* ... still in OpenGL context ... */

cudaGraphicsResource* pGraphicResource = 0;
cudaError_t eError = cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(
  &pGraphicResource, 
  nTextureID, 
  GL_TEXTURE_3D, 
  cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsSurfaceLoadStore);
```

Whatever I do or change concerning the texture's format and/or data type I always get cudaErrorUnknown for eError. I can't believe that the error is because of chosing a wrong format, because the official documentation ([external link](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__OPENGL_gd7be3ca8a7a739d57f0b558562c5706e.html#gd7be3ca8a7a739d57f0b558562c5706e)) says, that all these formats are supported.

**So my question to you: What other reasons may the cudaErrorUnknown have in this context?**

By the way: I didn't use a call of cudaSetDevice or cudaGLSetGLDevice before. When I do so I get problems with "Runtime API error : all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable". But I have proved that the index of the current device is the same and a valid one (my Quadro 600) before and after the call.

My GPU: NVIDIA Quadro 600
My SDK: NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit v4.1

Comment: Dare one ask what `unsigned char* pData = new unsigned char*[2*256*256*256]();` is supposed to be?

Comment: Yeah, even without the bizarre function call `()` at the end, you want to allocate an array of `char`, not and array of `char*`, right?  Also, do you ever call `glBindTexture()`?

Comment: @talonmies you're right, that was a typing error.

Comment: @harrism yes, i call that before when I create my texture. Or do you mean that the texture has to be bind again before I call cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage?

Comment: @harrism OK, that might be the problem. I expected the opposite like it is described in this tutorial http://rauwendaal.net/2011/12/02/writing-to-3d-opengl-textures-in-cuda-4-1-with-3d-surface-writes/. I will give it a try on monday.

Comment: I deleted that comment because you are right, the texture ID is specified in the call, so perhaps it doesn't need to be bound.  But That leads me to the cause of your error, I think.  See my answer below...

Comment: UPDATE: My problem still exists although I tried your proposals and even one more:

Comment: - another glBindTexture before call of cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage -> doesn't help!
- setting additional parameters for filtering and wrapping (I didn't use that before) --> doesn't work!

So my problem is still the same: I assume to have a correctly initialized and created GL_TEXTURE_3D element, accessible via nTextureID. A call to cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage always returns cudaError_t cudaUnknownError.

Comment: Another strange thing: cudaSetDevice / cudaGLSetGLDevice causes error "all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable" on first cuda call (e.g. cudaMalloc). So I spare these calls cause I could proof that the current device ids remain the same with or without the calls.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function of mine that prepares a texture and then registers it with CUDA. Maybe it can help you.

```
// Create a texture and register it for sharing with CUDA.
void CreateAndRegisterTex(GLuint& tex, cudaGraphicsResource*& resource, u32 w, u32 h) {
  u32 i(0);
  uchar4* buf((uchar4*)malloc(w * h * sizeof(uchar4)));
  glGenTextures(1, &tex);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  // glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); // program works without this but maybe it should be in there?
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_REPEAT);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
  free(buf);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  // Register this image for sharing with CUDA. cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage()
  // supports all texture formats with 1, 2, or 4 components and an internal
  // type of float (e.g. GL_RGBA_FLOAT32) and unnormalized integer (e.g.
  // GL_RGBA8UI). It does not currently support normalized integer formats (e.g.
  // GL_RGBA8). Please note that since GL_RGBA8UI is an OpenGL 3.0 texture
  // format, it can only be written by shaders, not the fixed function pipeline.
  cutilSafeCall(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&resource, tex, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                            cudaGraphicsMapFlagsWriteDiscard));
}
```

Before calling this function, I call:

```
InitGL(&argc, argv));
g_cuda_device = cutGetMaxGflopsDeviceId();
cudaSetDevice(g_cuda_device);
cudaGLSetGLDevice(g_cuda_device);
```

When changing the device to other than default, I call:

```
GLDeviceInit(g_cuda_device);
```

Comment: this is your tutorial http://rauwendaal.net/2011/12/02/writing-to-3d-opengl-textures-in-cuda-4-1-with-3d-surface-writes/, isn't it? In the source code you unbind the texture before the cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage-call, in your example above you explicitely bind it. can you explain that?

Comment: @morph: It's not my tutorial. I'm not sure if the unbind-free-bind sequence is necessary, but it does work.

Comment: Are you sure calling both `cudaSetDevice()` and `cudaGLSetGLDevice()` is a good idea? 
From the [Programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#graphics-interoperability): _"Note that `cudaSetDevice()` and `cudaGLSetGLDevice()` are mutually exclusive."_

Comment: @shinjin: Thank you for the information. I checked an older version of the CUDA C Programming Guide and it didn't have the language about the two calls being mutually exclusive. I'll check if the app works with only `cudaGLSetGLDevice()` and update the example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem (other than the strange `()` after your call to `new` -- what the heck is that?) is that you are passing an ID as the target parameter to `glTexImage3D`:

```
unsigned char* pData = new unsigned char[2*256*256*256](); // note weird parens here

glTexImage3D(
  nTextureID, // created before (glBindTexture etc.)
  0, 
  nInternalFormat, // GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA
  256, 
  256, 
  256, 
  0, 
  nDataFormat, // GL_LUMINANCE8_ALPHA8
  nDataType, // GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE
  pData);
```

The first argument of any `glTexImage*` call is the target, which is an `enum` value, not the texture ID.  What you should have is something like this:

```
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

glTexImage3D(
  GL_TEXTURE_3D,
  0, 
  nInternalFormat, // GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA
  256, 
  256, 
  256, 
  0, 
  nDataFormat, // GL_LUMINANCE8_ALPHA8
  nDataType, // GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE
  pData);
```

So I think this is an OpenGL problem, not a CUDA problem -- if you check for GL errors you will probably see an invalid value error or something after the `glTexImage3D` call.  The fact that there is a GL error state probably explains why you get `cudaErrorUnknown`.

Comment: OFFTOPIC: (other than the strange () after your call to new -- what the heck is that?) --> don't ask me where I got this from, but I've just reproofed this in vs10's debugger: The additional use of the ()-operator initializes the array with 0

Comment: I'm sorry for that fault, this is a part I assume to be correct, because it is done somewhere else in our huge framework. I just work with an Object containing the already initialized textureID, so I sketched this glTexImage3D-code above for a more comprehensive context and a hint to the glBindTexture call.

Comment: What is the value of `nTextureID`?  The first argument to `glTexImage3D` must be `GL_TEXTURE_3D`, as I stated.  If `nTextureID` has some other value than that, then it's probably wrong.

Comment: As I already mentioned my code that contains glTexImage3D is just a placeholder for some external library stuff. But I could proof that the library calls the glTexImage3D function correctly.

Comment: In your question your code still passes `nTextureID` for the target parameter of `glTexImage3D`.  As long as your code does that here, I can only assume it does that in the real world, which would be an error.  If this is just pseudocode, then it will be difficult for anyone to help.